# SPUtility.SendEmail works but will not send links

Tags: 2010, email, sputility

In SP 2010, I'm using SPUtility.SendEmail and it is working fine except for sending links. In the body string argument, I input

```
"<a href=\"http://www.google.com\">Click me</a>"
```

It appears in the email as the html code that I want (the text code, I can't put it here because it will be formatted to be a link)

And when I view the source of the email, I see

```
&lt;a href=&quot;http://www.google.com&quot;&gt;Click me&lt;/a&gt;
```

I know html is working as I am using bold and newline tags, but I can't figure out how to get the link to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    public static bool SendEmail(
    SPWeb web,
    bool fAppendHtmlTag,
    bool fHtmlEncode,
    string to,
    string subject,
    string htmlBody)
```

You should set the parameters:

**fAppendHtmlTag**
true to append an HTML tag to the message; otherwise, false.

**fHtmlEncode**
true to encode the message and replace characters in HTML tags with entities; otherwise, false.

Comment: That was it, I had them both set to true. Thank you!